# Spotlight can't find apps or folder, only seaches the web

Tags: macos, spotlight, search, indexing

My Spotlight can't find any apps, even the native ones. It only returns results from web searches. With a little googling I found out that a pretty common solution to that is to rebuild the indexes. The problem is I can't do that: I tried a solution using the os interface (solution 1), but got the following error message:

[image]

An then I tried a manual solution, using the terminal (solution 2), but then this happened:

[image]

I don't know what else to try. Does anyone have been through that?
I'm using El Capitan latest version (10.11.6). Thanks!

PS.: I tried to post the link to each solution, but I can't post more than 2 links because of my reputation. If someone needs them, I can share on the comment section.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obviously, Spotlight's index is misbehaving, and you did the right thing using the mdutil command. If repeating that command merely provides the same "Index is already changing state..." result, then the situation requires you to manually remove Spotlight's data directory. It's simple enough to do and it's perfectly safe, but it would still be wise to run a backup before proceeding. Then:

1.) In the Terminal, issue the command

```
sudo rm -r /.Spotlight-V100
```

2.) Restart in Safe Mode

- Restart your Mac, and immediately after you hear the startup sound, press and hold the Shift key.
- Release the Shift key when you see the Apple logo appear on the screen.

3.) Restart (in standard mode) after Safe Mode startup is complete. Spotlight will begin indexing using the preferences you have set for it.

Comment: Thanks! It worked! Also: very good explanation!
I would leave an upvote, but don't have reputation to do so!

Comment: **Update:** I need to repeat the process each time I turn on my mac, but instead of restarting, I'm doing:
`sudo rm -r /.Spotlight-V100`
`sudo mdutil -i off`
`sudo mdutil -i on`

Do you have any idea of how to fix this permanently...

Comment: This is the first I've heard of Spotlight needing to be continually reset with every restart. I'll look around for possible answers, but I have no advice for you now. Sorry, Miguel.

Answer (score 1):

In Finder, go up to where it says "Finder" in bold in the menubar (upper left) and select "Preferences." Under the "Advanced" tab, make sure "When Performing a Search: Search this Mac" is selected.

[image: Finder Preferences]

Then go into System Preferences and select "Spotlight." Under "Search Results," make sure everything is checked off.

[image: Spotlight Preferences]

**EDIT #1:**

Go into System Preferences > Spotlight > Security. Make sure your list is empty. This is a list of files NOT to search, and if your drive is listed, it won't search it.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However, my Finder preferences were already set to that, altough you have more options in yours. ([image](http://imgur.com/a/SiKST)). Also, in Spotlight preferences, every options is checked, like your screenshot. Any more ideas?

Comment: Is [this](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201716) how you rebuilt the indexes? Is that what gave you the "Privacy List Error?" Are you an admin on your computer?

Comment: See my **EDIT #1** in the above answer.

Comment: Tried that, but always got the error I show in that first image. Doc G. solution solves the issue, but thanks for helping! :)

Comment: +1 This answer is in line with the official Apple support document: https://support.apple.com/en-ke/HT201716